# How can i save files on my hard drive

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

as i am new on ubuntu operating system.
how can i save my files , music , photos , doc , ect.
on my hard drive i got two partition each 300GB.
and filesystem.

when i open the partition i found in it files and doc , and i can't remove it.
and also i can't save any thing on my partition i just want to save my files like i always done on windows so what ever happen my files is save on my hard drive.
the partition location is ( /media )
file system type ext3/ext4

P.S : i think this is because it's not a writeable.

so how can i fix it or save files like on window .

Hope for a fast replay , with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that you own the partition.
Go to Media then right click on the icon then go to properties.
On the middle tab you can see the owner.
If it is **root** then open a terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+T 
and type the following command: 
    `sudo chown --recursive [yourUserName]:[yourUserName] [pathToPartitionFolder]`
without the []
and enter your password when asked. 
Where [pathToPartitionFolder] is something like /media/7a8s87d8. 
Try to write a file on the partition.

If you are the owner   but it is not writeable  then make it writeable by changing the rights on the middle tab of properties.